# What is the best way to check string not null and not empty in Java?

Tags: java, string, performance, compare

I consider bewteen `!StringUtils.isEmpty(string)` and `string != null && string.length()!=0` Which is better for performance??

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference?

Comment: Which StringUtils are you talking about? Apache Commons? Spring?

Comment: Hi shmosel, I think they will bring different performance

Comment: Hi Mateusz Mrozewski, I talked about Apache Commons

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer `string != null && !string.isEmpty()`. The intent is  clear and why rely on an external library for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

There's no relevant performance difference. When the code gets used a lot, the utility method gets inlined and then it's exactly the same. When it doesn't get used, then nobody cares.

Performance is sometimes important, but such trivialities have no impact. Learn Java benchmarking (JMH) before you even start thinking about optimizations.

In case you already use Apache Commons, then use their utility methods. If you don't than don't bring the library in just because of such a triviality. OTOH there are many other useful things in the library (FWIW I started with some trivial methods from Guava and now I use a substantial portion of it).